# jQuery AJAX is converting the string escape from %20 to +

Tags: javascript, ajax, urlencode, stringescapeutils

I have a jQuery AJAX function that saves an image path to the database. Here is an examples parameter:

```
var data = {};
data['url'] = "Path%20to%20URL";
```

If there is a space or %20, it will be saved as `"Path%20to%20URL"` in the database. I haven't changed anything to my code but now, it is saved as
`"Path+to+URL"`. Any Idea what's the cause of this?

I already tried to use

```
str.replaceAll('+', '%20')
```

in my code just in case it is caused by another function. but no luck.

Here is my jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
      url: `server-url`,
      type: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        //auth keys
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      success: () => {
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Path%20to%20URL"`, this is the encoded type of path in HTML. You can use `decodeURI()` function in this case.

```
var data = {};

data['url'] = "Path%20to%20URL";
console.log(decodeURI(data['url']));

//"Path to URL"
```

Comment: You should always use `decodeURIComponent` for anything that is not an absolute URI. See [MDN for why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI#decodeuri_vs_decodeuricomponent)

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question of why jQuery AJAX is changing `%20` to `+`.